# How should I build custom history tracking for a custom object and save in another custom object?

Tags: apex, trigger

Here's the code which i implemented, your help is greatly appreciated.

Object to track history: Student__c

Object to save history of Student__c: Student_History__c

```
trigger StudentHistory on Student__c (after update) {
//get all fields from compliance that we want to check for changes
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> allComplFieldsMap = Schema.SObjectType.Student__c.fields.getMap();
   system.debug('Intial allComplFieldsMap:'+allComplFieldsMap);
    Map<String, Schema.DescribeFieldResult> complFieldsToTrack = new Map<String, Schema.DescribeFieldResult>();
    List<Student_History__c> historiesToInsert = new List<Student_History__c>();
    system.debug('Intial histories to Insert:'+historiesToInsert);
    for (Schema.SObjectField complField : allComplFieldsMap.values()) {
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult describeResult = complField.getDescribe();
        //choose which fields to track depending on the field type
        if (describeResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Boolean ||
            describeResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Combobox ||
            describeResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Currency ||
            describeResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Date ||
            describeResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.DateTime ||
            describeResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Double ||
            describeResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Email ||
            describeResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Integer ||
            describeResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.MultiPicklist ||
            describeResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Percent ||
            describeResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Phone ||
            describeResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Picklist ||
            describeResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.String ||
            describeResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.TextArea ||
            describeResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Time ||
            describeResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.URL) 
        {
            //don't add standard fields that are not necessary
            if (describeResult.getName() != 'CreatedDate' &&
                describeResult.getName() != 'LastModifiedDate' &&
                describeResult.getName() != 'SystemModstamp' &&
                //only add fields that are visible to the current user
                describeResult.isAccessible() &&
                //do not add formula fields
                !describeResult.isCalculated()
                )
            {
                complFieldsToTrack.put(describeResult.getName(), describeResult);

            }
        }
        for(Student__c std: Trigger.New){
        Student__c oldCompl = Trigger.oldMap.get(std.Id);
        Student__c newCompl = Trigger.newMap.get(std.Id);

    for (Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldDescribe : complFieldsToTrack.values()) {
        if (oldCompl.get(fieldDescribe.getName()) != newCompl.get(fieldDescribe.getName())) {
            Student_History__c complHistory = createUpdateHistory(fieldDescribe, oldCompl, newCompl);
            historiesToInsert.add(complHistory);            
        }
    }
        }
    } 

    system.debug('Second complFieldsToTrack:'+complFieldsToTrack);
     system.debug('Second histories to Insert:'+historiesToInsert);

    private Student_History__c createUpdateHistory(Schema.DescribeFieldResult field, Student__c oldCompl, Student__c newCompl) {
    Student_History__c complHistory = new Student_History__c();
    complHistory.StdHisId__c = newCompl.Id;
   // complHistory.Event__c = 'Edit';
    complHistory.StdNameHis__c = field.getLabel();
    complHistory.CourseInterestHis__c = field.getLabel();
    complHistory.EmailHis__c = field.getLabel();
    complHistory.GenderHis__c = field.getLabel();
    complHistory.MobileHis__c = field.getLabel();    
    //complHistory.User__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
    // shorten strings that are longer than 255 characters (can happen if the field has the type textArea)
    if (complHistory.StdHisId__c != null) complHistory.StdHisId__c = complHistory.StdHisId__c.abbreviate(255);
    if (complHistory.StdHisId__c != null) complHistory.StdHisId__c = complHistory.StdHisId__c.abbreviate(255);
    if (complHistory.StdNameHis__c != null) complHistory.StdNameHis__c = complHistory.StdNameHis__c.abbreviate(255);
    if (complHistory.StdNameHis__c != null) complHistory.StdNameHis__c = complHistory.StdNameHis__c.abbreviate(255);
    //complHistory.EditDate__c = System.now();
    return complHistory;
}
     if (!historiesToInsert.isEmpty()) {
        //remove duplicate history entries
        List<Student_History__c> historiesToInsertWithoutDuplicates = new List<Student_History__c>();
        Set<Student_History__c> historiesSet = new Set<Student_History__c>();
        historiesSet.addAll(historiesToInsert);
        historiesToInsertWithoutDuplicates.addAll(historiesSet);

        //insert the rest
        insert historiesToInsertWithoutDuplicates;
         system.debug('Histories with out Duplicates:'+historiesToInsertWithoutDuplicates);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of doing this custom history tracking? What is your archival strategy?

Comment: its my business requirement,  they want to track the history of object.